# Compare enum's and adding key word

Tags: c#

I created this sample and wanted any advice on how to make this code; cleaner, more effective, just overall better! I need to add the key word `and` only if the NegativeScheduleCalendar enum is before the ScheduleCalendar enum. The only way I was able to do this was to loop the list and checking if they are after each other. So the data has this `on Days - 7 and -1` and there is a ScheduleCalendar enum with data like this `on Days 1 - 21 and 25` the code below will add the `and` word.

```cs
int x = 0;
foreach (SentencePartTextHolder name in compiledSentenceParts)
{
    if (name.Type == SentencePartType.NegativeScheduleCalendar)
    {
        x = x + 1;
        if (x == 2)
        {
            string Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", NegativePositiveScheduleCalendarDelimiter, name.Text);
            name.Text = Text;
        }

    }
    else if (name.Type == SentencePartType.ScheduleCalendar)
    {
        x = x + 1;
        if (x == 2){
            string Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", NegativePositiveScheduleCalendarDelimiter, name.Text);
            name.Text = Text;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        x = 0;
    }
}
```

Sample project
https://dotnetfiddle.net/mCpBI9

Comment: Why do you use `string.Format`? Why do `string Text =` instead of simply assigning directly? Why write `x = x + 1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You differentiate between 3 cases, but two of them do exactly the same thing. Instead, use a logical OR (`||` in C#) to combine the two conditions.
- Use string interpolation instead of `String.Format`.
- You can eliminate the temp variable `Text`.
- Use the increment operator `++` to increment `x`.

```cs
int x = 0;

foreach (SentencePartTextHolder name in compiledSentenceParts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);

    if (name.Type == SentencePartType.NegativeScheduleCalendar ||
        name.Type == SentencePartType.ScheduleCalendar)
    {
        x++;
        if (x == 2)
        {
            name.Text = $"{NegativePositiveScheduleCalendarDelimiter} {name.Text}";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        x = 0;
    }
}
```

---

If you are using C# 9.0, you can use pattern matching to simplify the condition:

```cs
if (name.Type is SentencePartType.NegativeScheduleCalendar or
                 SentencePartType.ScheduleCalendar)
```

Note that you can switch to it like this in framework versions earlier than .NET 5: [C# language versioning](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version).

Yet another possibility is to use a switch statement:

```cs
switch (name.Type)
{
    case SentencePartType.NegativeScheduleCalendar:
    case SentencePartType.ScheduleCalendar:
        x++;
        if (x == 2)
        {
            name.Text = $"{NegativePositiveScheduleCalendarDelimiter} {name.Text}";
        }
        break;
    default:
        x = 0;
        break;
}
```

---

Incrementing `x` and then testing it can be combined by using the pre-increment operator

```cs
if (++x == 2)
```

Note that the `++` must be placed before the `x`, so that the already incremented `x` will be tested. If you write `if (x++ == 2)` then first `x` is compared to `2` and then only it is incremented.

---

**My final solution**

An alternative to counting the lines is to store the last `SentencePartType` and to compare it with the current one. Let us declare a little helper function:

```cs
private static bool IsCalendarType(SentencePartType type)
{
    return type is SentencePartType.NegativeScheduleCalendar or
                   SentencePartType.ScheduleCalendar;
}
```

Of course, you can also use the traditional Boolean logic here if you are working with a version prior to C# 9.0.

Now, we can rewrite the loop as

```cs
var lastType = SentencePartType.Undefined;
foreach (SentencePartTextHolder name in compiledSentenceParts)
{
    if (IsCalendarType(lastType) && IsCalendarType(name.Type))
    {
        name.Text = $"{NegativePositiveScheduleCalendarDelimiter} {name.Text}";
    }
    lastType = name.Type;
}
```

This looks much cleaner and is easier to understand. The expression `IsCalendarType(lastType) && IsCalendarType(name.Type)` expresses exactly what we are looking for.